# Python email package not working as expected?

Tags: python, email

I am trying a challenge on hackerrank. The text of the challenge says:

Hint: Try using Email.utils() to complete this challenge. For example, this code:

```
import email.utils
print email.utils.parseaddr('DOSHI <DOSHI@hackerrank.com>')
print email.utils.formataddr(('DOSHI', 'DOSHI@hackerrank.com'))
```

produces this output:

```
('DOSHI', 'DOSHI@hackerrank.com')
DOSHI <DOSHI@hackerrank.com>
```

However, this is not the output I get when I run those 3 lines. I get the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-248-e5b75ae88af9>", line 2
    print email.utils.parseaddr('DOSHI <DOSHI@hackerrank.com>')
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - they probably created it in Python 2.
The code is missing the parents. The following works:

```
print(email.utils.parseaddr('DOSHI <DOSHI@hackerrank.com>'))
print(email.utils.formataddr(('DOSHI', 'DOSHI@hackerrank.com')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are importing email.utils() wrong.

Try this:

```
import email as e
print e.utils.parseaddr('DOSHI <DOSHI@hackerrank.com>')
print e.utils.formataddr(('DOSHI', 'DOSHI@hackerrank.com'))
```

plus if you are using python3, you have to add the brackets to your print function, like you said:

```
print (e.utils.parseaddr('DOSHI <DOSHI@hackerrank.com>'))
print (e.utils.formataddr('DOSHI', 'DOSHI@hackerrank.com'))
```